# How can I show or hide boot messages when Ubuntu starts?

Tags: boot, grub2

Is there a way to easily turn on/off showing the **boot messages** (loading the services) when Ubuntu starts? Is it something in Grub2?

I am running 10.04.

Comment: For one-time solution (not a permanent change), see https://askubuntu.com/a/25024/250300.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable boot messages to be printed on screen during boot up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You would need to edit the file `/etc/default/grub`.  In this file you'll find an entry called `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.  This entry must be edited to control the display of the splash screen.

The presence of the word `splash` in this entry enables the splash screen, with condensed text output.  Adding `quiet` as well, results in just the splash screen; which is the default for the desktop edition since 10.04 (Lucid Lynx).  In order to enable the "normal" text start up, you would remove both of these.

So, the default for the desktop, (i.e. splash screen only):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" #Hide text and show splash
```

For the traditional, text display:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=        #Show text but not the splash
```

For the splash, but the ability to show the boot messages by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"
```

Or, finally, for just a (usually) black screen, try:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet   #Don't show Ubuntu bootup text
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12" #Don't show kernel text
```

After editing the file, you need to run `update-grub`.

```
sudo update-grub
```

For more details, see this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Comment: How can you read that messages that are shown after you removed the `splash` from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT? I can see the messages now when I start, but then X starts and they are gone.

Comment: `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` and `GRUB_TIMEOUT` causes confusion don't understand why they keep two of these settings and displays the error `Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported`

Comment: @rubo77 The dmesg command: http://superuser.com/questions/176165/where-linux-places-the-messages-of-boot

Comment: For anybody in 2023 with Ubuntu 22.04 that keeps getting circled back to this thread like me, set `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `"quiet splash"` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to `"console=ttyS0"`. YMMV but this helps me achieve manufacturer logo and no grub output all the way from boot to login.

Answer (score 32):

I may be out of subject, but you can just press "escape" during boot, to show/hide the plymouth splash screen...

Comment: By "easily turn on/off", I think it's just what he/she wants.

Comment: Does that work on 10.04?

Comment: Yes. I actually tested it on both Lucid Lynx Desktop and Netbook editions before posting :-)

Comment: It works only if grub is not quiet, i.e.:

    `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash"`

Answer (score 10):

There's a simple way of hiding all boot messages. In `/etc/default/grub`, adjust the following:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 # Do not show the GRUB menu at all
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12" # Redirect the kernel output to another tty
```

After that, just `sudo update-grub`, and it should be done.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in 18.04

Comment: `console=ttyS0` does seem to work in 18.04, I found that as answer to my own question. I may do some more research on it later on, though. See https://askubuntu.com/q/1085629/295286

Answer (score 6):

If you remove `quiet` option from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to show boot messages it's sometimes necessary to also set `loglevel` option to higher value. Otherwise some drivers may flood your `tty` with notice messages. I use this line to enable boot messages:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=4"
```

This way only significant system messages will be printed to the console.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't identify whether you are on a server system or desktop, so I'll address both.

If you add `splash` to `/etc/default/grub/` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, Ubuntu will present you with a splash screen, either a simple text based progress bar or graphically via `plymouth`, which I describe below.

Using `plymouth`, a graphical startup animator, you can provide a pretty bootscreen that is well suited to desktop machines. You might not want to do this on a server, but it's up to you.

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth"` to tell my laptop to not show me the startup picture but the boot messages … still works for 11.10