# How to enable boot messages to be printed on screen during boot up?

Tags: boot, kernel, syslog

How to enable boot messages, kernel messages and other logs of various services to be printed on screen during boot up?

Comment: Voting to reopen. Both this and the [target question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts) are not specific but the answers here also provide a non-permanent solution (which is the only available if boot does not succeed.)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You'd need to remove the kernel boot parameters *quiet* and *splash* from the *linux* line in GRUB:

1. Start your system and wait for the GRUB menu to show (if you don't see a GRUB menu, press and hold the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key right after starting the system).
2. Now highlight the kernel you want to use, and press the <kbd>e</kbd> key. You should be able to see and edit the commands associated with the highlighted kernel.
3. Go down to the line starting with `linux` and remove the parameters `quiet` and `splash`.
4. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

To make this change permanent:

1. From a terminal (or after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) run:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   and enter your password.
2. Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and remove the parameters `quiet` and `splash`.
3. Save the file and close the editor.
4. Finally, start a terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   to update GRUB's configuration file.

Comment: I this still the recommended way? I remember that there is a keyboard shortcut you can press already during the boot process, during the splash screen, which will switch to the boot messages.

Comment: There is a variable $vt_handoff passed as argument in the linux line, that must be removed manually and update-grub readds it... so the solution is editing grub.cfg manually also.

Answer (score 7):

Edit you bootloader kernel command-line and remove `quiet` argument. You may also want to remove `splash` argument to disable graphical animation during boot to be able to see the console with messages.

Answer (score 6):

In more recent releases, including 12.04 and 12.10 it is also necessary to either delete, or change the `GFXMODE` line to `text`, as well as removing `quiet` and `splash`. (See the other answers.)

When making the changes permanent find the commented line:

```
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
```

and remove the beginning `#`, so it is no longer a comment, and also set its value to `text`.

With the latter change the menu will be white on black in a larger text font, and therefore hold fewer entries, but the messages should be visible once an item is selected for booting.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> during the initial stage of booting.

Answer (score 1):

Remove these 3 words/variable from linux command line:

```
quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

End add the argument to force verbosing:

```
debug
```

My linux line looks like this:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-142-generic root=UUID=14xxee5-1e84-4xx5-9e17-a6xx5 ro debug
```