# Howto enable boot messages in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: boot, startup, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable boot messages to be printed on screen during boot up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up)

Hello when I do reboot or init 6 in console under ubuntu 12.04 my system does not start correctly. it freezes in startup process.

Wow can I enable the boot-messages instead of the splash-screen.

Is this still valid for ubuntu 12.04?
[How to enable boot messages to be printed on screen during boot up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up)

Comment: I would suggest that you try the duplicate - if it does not work - a small bounty asking for an update usually works.

Comment: I've added another answer to the referenced question to update it for more recent releases. The graphics need to be set or reset to text mode to see the messages. Please comment on the referenced question if you find problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. the link is still valid. You can use both methods(editing the GRUB file, and editing the command-line during boot).