# Ubuntu studio freeze when starting the system

Tags: freeze, system

i would to ask that question: why freeze my ubuntu studio when system starting ? anyway ubuntu studio is great i love it only then freeze, and I dont know why ?

**EDIT from comments (paraphrased):**

I see only ubuntu logo rotate... and after 20 min still nothing (no boot?)

Comment: What's on the screen, when Ubuntu freezes? If it's all garbled, what's the last thing you see?

Comment: David Foster: I seen only ubuntu logo rotate... :( nothing else :( and after 20 min noting happened

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](/q/4408), because the “freeze“ happens during boot. [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](/q/162075/175814) would be much better in my opinion.

Comment: @DavidFoerster They both are feasibly related IMHO. The first covers many issues including possible hardware problems, The second appears to be more GRUB focused which could also be the issue. The problem is that we don't have enough information to determine which.

Comment: Add more information, please. remove `quiet splash` from the boot options and then tell us where it stops exactly. Follow [these instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up/25024?s=3|0.0000#25024) how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you can access the terminal then try the steps in this [link](http://itsfoss.com/fix-unity-freezes-after-login-ubuntu-14-04/) 
.if you can't then from grub menu select ubuntu generic(recovery mode).once you get into ubuntu try to fix it using above link.

if you experiencing frezze after logged in then this  [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes) may helpful.

Comment: I have ubuntu studio and xfce , because this not help me... I tried recovery mode not helped... :( –