# How do I upgrade from linux kernel 2.6.33.5-rscloud

Tags: kernel, vps

I have a VPS, which used to be on Slicehost and now Rackspace and it's running kernel 2.6.33.5-rscloud with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. It seems I can't update my packages without getting onto a more recent kernel.

I've been trying various kernels and they all halt at startup, with different error messages. My menu.lst clearly controls which kernel I boot and I can change the default, watch it fail, and the change it back to zero in rescue mode.

```
/boot/grub/menu.lst

default     0

title    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, kernel 2.6.33.5-rscloud
root     (hd0,0)
kernel   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.33.5-rscloud root=/dev/sda1 ro quiet splash console=xvc0 selinux=0
initrd   /boot/initrd.img-2.6.33.5-rscloud

title    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, kernel 3.16.0-77-generic
root     (hd0,0)
kernel   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-77-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro quiet splash console=xvc0 selinux=0
initrd   /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-77-generic

title    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-116-generic
root     (hd0,0)
kernel   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic root=/dev/sda1 ro quiet splash console=xvc0 selinux=0
initrd   /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
```

I've been playing with grub, grub2, pvgrub without success. I've had issues not finding the boot device (disable UUID) and problems with the realtime clock in the later kernels. I'd prefer not to build a new server from scratch as I have many services running well and various DNS services pointing to its IP.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to upgrade a custom kernel to a generic kernel...  Have you contacted product support already as they might have built in some custom functionality for their specific storage that the mainline kernel is not aware of...

Comment: Please remove quite splash from the kernel command line and update grub (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up). Add the output to your question

Comment: What if you update the ubuntu version to a more recent one?  Ubuntu 17.10 for instance?