# How to get Lubuntu 22.04 to display startup or boot messages

Tags: lubuntu, plymouth

I recently installed Lubuntu 22.04 on my HP laptop and today I decided to remove the Plymouth splash screen permanently and view the "old school" boot messages instead. At first, I tried to do this by removing "quiet" and "splash" next to the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" entry in GRUB. That didn't remove the splash screen, so I decided to remove Plymouth altogether using Synaptic and some instructions I found on a website. While that successfully removed the splash screen, the boot messages do not show at all when the system is starting up, nor does pressing the "Esc" key make them appear. I've tried three or four different solutions, including uncommenting "GFXMODE" and changing the parameter to "text," but to no avail. Does anyone know of a way I get the boot messages to appear reliably each time I start the OS? :-)

In case it helps, here is one of the pages where I sought information t resolve this problem...

[How to enable boot messages to be printed on screen during boot up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up)

Thank you for your time and any help you can offer! :-)

Regards...

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` after editing `/etc/default/grub` ?

Comment: I'm with @sudodus and suspect what you may have done is correct, you just didn't complete what you did do.  When you say you removed "*"quiet" and "splash"*" you didn't say where you removed it; I read it as during a boot via an edit at grub, which will achieve exactly what you want, but only for the current session. You didn't say where you made the change, thus we don't know when it'll take effect. It may take effect on next `update-grub` after a kernel upgrade, which is why it was suggested to run the command to cause it to occur now. You weren't clear as to exactly what you did.

Comment: Hi sudodus and guiverc, thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it! Problem solved, praise be to God! It turns out that I did indeed modify the wrong GRUB file. I changed the one in "usr/share/grub/default," not the one in "etc/default/grub" because I didn't initially see the GRUB file in "etc." So, as a result, I thought that I didn't have such a file, even though "grub-update" was sourcing the information from there. Whoops! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction and causing me to take a second look! This thread is now "SOLVED!" Thank you guys again for your help! :-)

Comment: Well done for solving it..  You should have put your last comment (*how you corrected your situation, what you did that fixed it*) in the Answer section of this page, so you can accept it as the answer (*gaining reputation points for this site*). We are both glad you got it solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying you may need to *completely uninstall* "plymouth" and all plymouth related packages, including the configuration files located in the "/usr/share/plymouth" directory, for this to work. However, please be warned, even though I didn't experience any problems myself, this may have unintended consequences and create errors and other problems in your operating system, including a failure to boot, from what I've heard. Just try just editing the GRUB file in "etc" first and see if that works for you. :-)

Per guiverc's suggestion, I decided to post what I did to resolve the issue in case it helps anyone else. After reading sudodus's and guiverc's questions and suggestions, I did the following...

1. I brought up the file manager "pcmanfm-qt" and went to the location "/etc/default/grub" to see if I could find the GRUB file I didn't see in my initial search. Praise God I did this time! :-)
2. I brought up a terminal or command line window (QTerminal) and used the "gksudo pcmanfm-qt" command to bring up a file manager in root, where I was able to access and open the GRUB file (using gedit) in "/etc/default/grub" and modify the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT" line to look like this...

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

PLEASE NOTE: The "gksu" package has been deprecated and has not been offered in the repositories since 16.04, I believe. Therefore, unless you install the necessary packages manually, you will not be able to use the command I used above. Now, one way to open a file manager in root is to use the "pkexec" command, or specifically `pkexec pcmanfm-qt` (in the case of Lubuntu.) However, I ran into errors trying to use "pkexec" that I didn't know how to resolve, so I just installed "gksu," a program that I'm used to and like better. There are probably ways to accomplish the same task using the terminal but I'm not well versed enough with the CLI to offer suggestions using that method. Please see the following pages linked to below for more information...

https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/

[How to configure pkexec?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287845/how-to-configure-pkexec)

3. I then saved the changes, closed all the windows I had opened and then opened up a new terminal window and ran the command `sudo update-grub` and waited for the program to complete its work. I then closed the window and rebooted the system.
4. Voila! Problem solved, praise be to God! I now have lots and lots of boot messages! :-D

Thank you to everyone on Ask Ubuntu who has posted answers to help others resolve their Ubuntu (or Ubuntu flavor) related issues! Your help is very much a blessing! :-)

Regards...

Comment: You mention "*etc/default/grub*" which is a relative path (ie. based on your $PWD or present working directory) where you mean `/etc/default/grub` or a defined path (*only the same if you're located in / when command is provided*).  You mention `plymouth` which I can't see how its packages relates; your purpose was to not use it which doesn't require it's uninstall.  I'd also not use `gksudu` as it makes little sense on a Qt5 desktop (Lubuntu uses LXQt & thus Qt5 not GTK/gk) let alone it being long *deprecated*.  FYI: I also see Lubuntu as Ubuntu (it's a *flavor* not derivative)  but Thank You

Comment: Hi guiverc! Thank you for sharing your thoughts, I made a couple changes in my post above to reflect your suggestions. I know that using "gksudo" or the "gksu" program isn't recommended but for me personally, I've only had mixed success using "pkexec" and I don't like it as much as "gksu." But that's just my personal preference. :-)