# Can't Boot Ubuntu lts version 22.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Subject: Boot Stuck Issue with LTS Version on Ubuntu Installation

Hello Ask Ubuntu community,

I am encountering an issue with the LTS version of Ubuntu during the installation process. After preparing a bootable USB for the LTS version and selecting "Try" or "Install Ubuntu," the system gets stuck in the loading phase at the console.

Interestingly, I do not face the same problem when attempting to install version 21 or 23; the installation process for these versions is smooth.

I would appreciate any suggestions or fixes from the community to address this problem with the LTS version. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has recommendations for troubleshooting, please share your insights.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Try to [enable boot messages to be printed on screen during boot up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25022/how-to-enable-boot-messages-to-be-printed-on-screen-during-boot-up), and share the output.  (Please, in a readable format, so no PHOTO of your screen  .... )

Comment: version 21 or 23?   Please be specific with details; there is no 21 or 23, but 21.04, 21.10, 23.04 & 23.10.  Also there are different Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ISOs, for Server, Desktop that use different installers. We can provide more accurate advice if you're clear with details & we thus know what you're using. Did you verify ISO prior to write of media? & was the write of ISO to media checked?  Did you *clone* (ie. no change) the ISO? or reformat it during write? as *clone* is best to have it work on all hardware, re-format of ISO can make it fail to work on some hardware...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)