# How do I disable kernel messages while booting?

Tags: boot, kernel, log

I enabled the kernel messages a long time ago because I was playing around with Ubuntu. But now I am finished and I want to disable them again, but forgot how to.

`/etc/default/grub` already contains the line:

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

(including the hash which disables it).

Comment: Check if `/etc/default/grub` has the following line uncommented `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`. If yes, then open it with `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, add a `#` in the beginning of that line and save. Do not change anything else.

Comment: @max: Did you read [http://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts](http://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts) ? If you did then mentioning that in the OP might help prevent duplicate answer which did not work for you. If you did not then we can close this as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

The `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` definition in `/etc/default/grub` should contain `"quiet splash"`.  You also need Plymouth to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `/etc/default/grub` has the line `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` uncommented. Either open it with any editor, or just run this in the terminal:

```
cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_TERMINAL
```

If the output is `GRUB_TERMINAL=console` without a `#`, then open the file with `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`, add a `#` at the beginning of that line and save. Do not change anything else.

Comment: Was arleady with #