# What does `printf` do in rc.local?

Tags: bash, startup

I've encountered an `/etc/rc.local` script that gets some data and uses `printf` on it.

My question is: where does that data that is printed go when `rc.local` is executed on startup? Is there a log file or something I can look in to get it?

Comment: Unless you redirect the output, it will be printed on the screen during the boot process. The boot messages are supressed / hidden and go by fast. Remove the boot options quiet and splash to see the messages. They should be in /var/log/messages and/or in dmesg

Comment: The output is not redirected, so it should directly as boot messages. It is on a headless computer, so knowing about `/var/log/messages` is what I was looking for.  Put all that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you redirect the output, it will be printed on the screen during the boot process. The boot messages are supressed / hidden and go by fast.

Remove the boot options quiet and splash to see the messages.

See [How can I show or hide boot messages when Ubuntu starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts) for details.

They should be in the logs, ( /var/log/messages ) and/or in dmesg