# Hide disk information displayed on boot?

Tags: boot, 16.04, startup

I was wondering if there was any way to hide the disc information message (the one that says `X blocks available, X blocks safe` or something to that effect. Not sure what that's called.) that I get on start-up. Not that the information isn't helpful, it's just a message which causes unnecessary worry by reminding me of when my previous hard drive was failing. So, like, is there a way to either hide this behind a fancy start-up animation, or even have it buried within the wall of text that just confirms the computer's capabilities (again, not sure what it's called. It's the one that just says `[OK] USB Keyboard` and stuff like that).

Comment: Are referring to the information that gets displayed while ubuntu boots ???

Comment: Yes, I believe so. But it's oddly just information about the Disk, no other information is displayed.

Comment: Do you have the `quiet splash` boot parameters disabled which cause Ubuntu to show up the purple boot screen with the cycling dots?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the display of *text information* as Ubuntu boots you will need to edit your *grub* here `/etc/default/grub`.

Change :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=    #shows text but not splash screen
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"   #no text but shows splash screen
```

I am assuming that you have it set to the first example, hence the information your seeing.

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts) for a comprehensive explanation.