# How to **really** suppress kernel messages during boot?

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, logging

I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS. I want to suppress kernel messages shown on console during boot. (The type of `[0.1234] kernel message` thing that floods the screen ).

**THIS DID NOT WORK**:

- [Changing /etc/systl.conf](https://superuser.com/a/351402/418028)
- Setting `LogLevel=err` or `LogLevel=emerg` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`. This did in fact remove `[ ok ] Blah blah` type of messages but not `[123.456] Something something` type.
- [Changing GRUB settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/289/295286). Even `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=3 rd.systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log-priority=3 loglevel=0"`
   ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1164531/418028)). No, difference in `loglevel=0` or `loglevel=3`. No, I did not forget to run `sudo update-grub`.
- `sudo dmesg -n 1` ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1283707/418028))
- [This,too](https://askubuntu.com/q/1043532/295286). Don't mark this question as duplicate of that since `agetty` is completely unrelated to boot messages and OP's own answer does not work, like I mentioned above about `GRUB` part.
- editing `/etc/systemd/journal.conf` to set `ForwardToWall=no` or `MaxLevelWall=emerg`
- setting `console=tty5` in `/etc/default/grub` ( [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009678/295286) )
- I removed `plymouth` completely - the messages still appear. Which also makes sense since it's not related to plymouth, it's not even started as service in systemd, and there's no GUI on this system.

I'll probably be offering a bounty to the answer that can make a perfectly quiet boot setting and maybe downvote all those other answers because they're outdated and not useful at all and don't work at all. I've spent quite a considerable time on trying to figure this out with not much results.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev  Simply to have a clear screen during boot up until  login prompt shows up cleanly, without boot messages mangling text when I type in my username and password and driving me mad ?

Comment: I started to research this but a super-sleuth such as yourself would probably do better: Redirect `/dev/tty` or `/dev/console` to a file so it's never displayed on screen?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix But it's Ubuntu Server. I do need to use `/dev/tty1`. I mean, i could switch to tty2, but . . . that's hacky

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of post you linked (https://askubuntu.com/a/1067093/702388). I'm happy with no kernel messages at all; have you tried my solution(s)? Seems like to be very close to what you need...

Comment: @donlucacorleone  Yes, I have tried that. Altering values in `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"` hasn't helped.  As I posted below,  the only thing that did is setting `console=ttyS0` , i.e. redirecting where console messages go

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I'm new to Linux system, but I think you should set all of them: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"`, 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet"`, 
`GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0`

Comment: @LucaM Well, if you read [GRUB's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variables pass parameters to kernel. The `quiet` parameter in [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)  is referenced as "Disable most log messages", which it indeed would do in versions prior to 15.04, but now that Ubuntu switched to `systemd` init subsystem, this doesn't seem to work anymore, at least in my experience.

Comment: @LucaM `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` is not referenced in docs, but from brief research it doesn't have to do  with kernel messages, but rather with failed boot ( [see ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) )

Comment: @LucaM As far as `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` settings go, I've tried them over and over in multiple variations without any positive result.   And yes, I tried the complete 3 settings too even though I know one of them is pointless. Did not work.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Maybe you can try to reinstall the whole OS, or perhaps using 18.04 **.1** ... I'm sorry I don't know how to help you further :-(

Comment: @LucaM  It's alright :) Not that big of an issue, but it just was very annoying. I may give 18.04.1 a go in virtual machine.  Thanks for trying to help, though, I do appreciate that :) I'll update this post if I can find anything further

Answer (score 5):

So apparently `console=tty5` doesn't work or any virtual console for that matter. What does seem to work is `console=ttyS0` set in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` (the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` doesn't work for some reason, even though that option should send kernel parameters to normal boot, while `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` - to both diagnostic and normal). I'll update this answer if I figure out anything else but so far this seems to be it.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me too on Ubuntu 19.04 Server!

Comment: Suggestion: Probably better to emphasize that the issue is applicable for Ubuntu Server only. The `console=` option does work for Ubuntu-based desktop flavours; I have tried with Xubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu MATE 18.04, via GRUB2 menu and GRUB2 configuration, and anyway had similar results.

Comment: is it possible to enable and disable this w/o a reboot??

Comment: @Gaia I dont think so, since that configuration file is read at boot time. If there is a way, I'm not aware of it

Comment: Apparently, this disables the splash screen too! Is there a way to supress kernel messages and keep the splash screen?