# Ubuntu 18.04. Can boot normally in Ubuntu (graphic mode) but get stuck in Recovery Mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

- I can boot normally in Ubuntu (graphic mode).
- When I boot in Recovery Mode it get stuck at `systemd-journald[270]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1`
- I have tried many things from the net without any results.
- Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In grub I changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12"` to hide kernel text [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts).

After removing `console=tty12` I could boot into recovery mode.

Tried this three times (adding and removing `console=tty12`) with same result.