# How can I see system logs while booting up ubuntu?

Tags: boot

When I am waiting for Ubuntu to boot, I can see the splash screen but it often freezes or is sometimes really show. I would like to troubleshoot my system.

How can I switch the screen to see what is happening while I wait for Ubuntu to boot?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/248/21005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the boot messages while Ubuntu is booting, press the `ESC` key after the GRUB menu. This way you can see where Ubuntu gets stuck and figure out how to fix your machine without having to use a command line or a recovery disk.