# Connect to remote Ubuntu laptop which does not load

Tags: bootloader, remote-access

I suspect the answer but still want to try. I have a relative who's got a laptop with Ubuntu. She just uses it for Internet browsing and she's not technical at all. Her laptop stopped loading. She's got a black screen and because she does not have a camera phone, I am not sure what is happening. I have been with her on the phone and it looks like GRUB works and we managed to get into Windows 7. However, she doesn't know how to use it and to get there every time looks too complex for her to do it on her own. I'd rather connect to her laptop remotely to try to fix it. Usually, I use TeamViewer but it's not an option now. I doubt she will be able to install it on Win7 and even if she does, I don't think it will help. I wonder if there is any default fallback way to connect to her laptop if it doesn't load Ubuntu. I have a feeling it might be some problem with a sys or boot drive being full or something. But to fix it,, I need to get connected.

Any help will be appreciated. Even if it's not possible without setting something, please mention it so I could have a fallback option in the future in case I manage to restore the laptop.

Comment: Have her record a video of the boot process using her phone. The video must be clear and stable, so you can read the text. At GRUB, have her [display boot messages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts). Network is not available until rather late in the boot process.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that she does not have a camera phone :-(