# Will my laptop HP 15bw088ax support Ubuntu? Does it contain the Wi-Fi driver already or do I have to install it separately?

Tags: drivers, wireless, system-installation, 20.04, bluetooth

My network adapter:
[image: My network adapter]

Bluetooth driver:
[image: Bluetooth driver]

My laptop specifications:

- HP 15 bw088ax
- AMD A9-9420 processor 2C+3G
- currently running on Windows

Do I need to be connected to internet to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Please redirect me to the already answered questions if there are any.

Comment: I need to know the details for wifi driver , as I currently do not have the facility to get wired connection.

Comment: We can't test your hardware, but you can! Try a live session and find out for yourself if the hardware is automatically supported. You don't need to be connected to the internet during system installation, but it does help to ensure that you have the right drivers and it helps reduce the amount of updates you will need to do immediately after installation.

Comment: I have ubuntu loaded to a 4gb Pendrive, can I use it to try a live session? Thanks for the help.

Comment: A live session is loaded fully into RAM. It won't alter anything on your device unless you instruct it to.

Comment: I tested a live session with Pendrive. It worked fine. I checked whatever I remembered like wifi, Bluetooth, ethernet, sound, etc. All these were working fine. Also, the drivers were detected automatically. So, can I fully load into my computer? It showed no problem while trying ubuntu.

Comment: Sounds like you'll have no issues running Ubuntu! If you encounter an issue during installation, you can ask!

Comment: I installed ubuntu without any problem. But when I boot the system, it shows a series of starting process with OK written. Is it normal or do i need some to work on it?

Comment: Yes that's normal!  You can hide it if you really want but make backups of any configs you change just in case you break something. For more info on the "verbose" booting see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts

Comment: Thanks @Nmath. I was afraid whether my system will support ubuntu or not. Your idea made me confident of installing ubuntu.