# How to completely hide boot messages on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: boot, command-line

I get these boot messages.

[image: blurry photo of screen]

How do I hide them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show or hide boot messages when Ubuntu starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution:

On the terminal, run

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now run

```
echo FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: Please don' t post link.only answers.

Comment: I have these setting, but still get loads of text during boot