# Disable text message on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, plymouth

I would like to totally disable text messages on boot. I would like to see only the plymouth animation.
I have this on my /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=0 systemd.log_level=0 rd.systemd.show_status=false rd.udev.log_level=0 splash net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 vt.global_cursor_default=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
```

But sometimes at the end of plymouth theme appear boot messages show in [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqisf.jpg).
**How it's possible disable and not only hide text boot message?**

The system version is Lubuntu 22.04LTS

Thanks Mauro

Comment: You could try fastboot kernel option.

Comment: **I don't think this is 100% achievable on all hardware**.. as I've found changes that will do it on 24 of 25 boxes; but there are the odd box around that has *firmware* that causes the kernel to spit out a message that can appear on some video cards (where all other devices are silenced). That 1 of 25 will need a different/unique config change.   *24 of 25 is guess, but I have >25 boxes I occasionally use in QA esp. with Lubuntu*

Answer (score 0):

Try edit your /etc/default/grub file like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=quiet   #Don't show Ubuntu bootup text
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12" #Don't show kernel text
```

After editing the file, you need to run update-grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts/289#289))

This might work, in my case no message is shown, but I have Ubuntu 22.04 with full disk encryption.

Sim.dll

Comment: This did not work for me unfortunately, thanks for your submission.