# Fsck logs on the screen

Tags: boot, grub2, fsck

I just install Ubuntu 22.10 and first that I notice is fsck logs on the screen before splash screen. I don't want watch this. So I found fsck.mode=skip, but I don't want turn off checking, FRAMEBUFFER=y > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash, but I don't know how it works, bu it works. Also I found [article on Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/silent_boot), but it Arch, Ubuntu haven't /etc/mkinitcpio.conf. Is it possible to adapt this article and the commands in it for Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show or hide boot messages when Ubuntu starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts)

Comment: No, didn't. I already try use these methods