# How to disable GUI for password prompt for encrypted LVM volumes on boot?

Tags: boot, lvm

How to disable GUI for password prompt for encrypted LVM volumes on boot and how to remove all strings on console output? I just need cleared prompt with blinking cursor.

[image]

[image]

And yes, I want to confuse anyone who tries to turn on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This should all be handled by [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth)

You could either:

- change the active splash theme

or

- deactivate the splash/Plymouth `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="noplymouth"`
- and disable console output using [`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty12"`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts)